# $http get loop append response data together

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have a list of links, with a number in each one from 1 up to however many there are. My goal is to write a for loop, that goes through each link, runs a HTTP get, then saves the response data to an array object. I have tried various methods, but its difficult because of the fact that I am dealing with $scope variables, so none of the methods I find work.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  $http.get("Start of URL"
+ i +  "End of URL")
  .then(function (response){
    $scope.datasingle = response.data;
  }); 
  $scope.datacombined = ??  

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way;

```
const promisses = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  promisses.push( new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    $http.get("Start of URL"+ i +  "End of URL").then(function(response){
      resolve(response.Data);
    });
  }));
}

Promise.all(promisses).then(function (values) {
  console.log(values); //you will get all the resolved result in this array and do what you want
});
```

Comment: Awesome thanks you. Going to look into some of these functions as I am not familiar with them all

Comment: Hi there, is there a way to instead of doing console.log(values) to somehow save it to a $scope variable? Cheers

Comment: try to use $scope.datacombined.push or something to save it to your scope instead console.log

Comment: cant quite figure it out - I'm going to try my example with the use of the .push and fingers crossed I can get something working, thanks!